# Double-columned in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, repeater

A dataset will be shown in 2 different columns.
Can I use for this the repeater-control or is there a more appropriate control ?
Does anyone know a good example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Repeater, a GridView or a DataList. The easiest way to show a dataset in columns is using a GridView.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548005.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The **datalist** control is a light weight control but has the advantage over the repeater control with 2 interesting properties:

- [RepeatColums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx)
- [RepeatDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx)

The ListView control is also a valuable alternative but it's more heavy weight so if you don't need all the extra fluff then I suggest the DataList control.